# Текст из буфера обмена

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Нужно как-то взять скопированный текст из буфера (я скопировал текст, через toast вывелось то, что я скопировал). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

String pasteData = "";

// If it does contain data, decide if you can handle the data.
if (!(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {



    } else if (!(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {

        // since the clipboard has data but it is not plain text

    } else {

        //since the clipboard contains plain text.
    ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

    // Gets the clipboard as text.
    pasteData = item.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177644/5330439) и [мануал](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно просто показать **тост** с подтверждением того, что данные скопированы, то не обязательно читать данные из буфера. Просто покажите тост с тем что было скопировано.

Здесь мы скопировали текст `getYourText()`.

```
ClipboardManager mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("mText", getYourText());
mClipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData );
```

И здесь мы его тут же показали.

```
Toast.makeText(this, getYourText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```