# Как занести информацию с буфера в переменную

Tags: java, android

Как занести информацию из буфера в переменную.

Что-то типа такого но только это   заносит в буфер а нужно наоборот !

```
 EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String copy_text = el2.getText().toString();

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = newPlainText("label",copy_text );
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [Текст из буфера обмена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760554/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(0);
String text = item.getText().toString();
```